# vector of pointers function returns unexpected value

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have this piece of code like:
(It meant to find the path of a node in the binary tree)

```
vector<TreeNode*> findPath(TreeNode* root, TreeNode *target, vector<TreeNode*> path) {
    if (root == target) {
        cout << path.size() << endl;  // the result is correct here
        return path;
    }
    if (root->left) {
        path.push_back(root->left);
        findPath(root->left, target,  path);
        path.erase(path.end()-1);
    }
    if (root->right) {
        path.push_back(root->right);
        findPath(root->right, target, path);
        path.erase(path.end()-1);
    }
}

int main(){

    TreeNode *root = new TreeNode(2);
    root->left = new TreeNode(1);

    vector<TreeNode*> path;
    path.push_back(root);

    vector<TreeNode*> getPath = findPath(root, root->left, path);
    cout << getPath.size() << endl; // here returns an UNEXPECTED value!
}
```

I mean the result is correct before it is returned.

But after it's returned, the result is wrong...

I have no idea what happened. =(

Comment: Sorry I meant UNexpected value in the 2nd comment. Also, this function meant to find the node and return its path. Thanks.

Comment: Your function logic is all messed up. You pass `path` by value everywhere, and return a changed path, but then you go `findPath(root->left, target,  path);` ignoring the return value.

Comment: Also you do not have a `return` statement in all cases for `findPath`; this causes undefined behaviour

Comment: I wonder your compiler doesn't tell you that `all control paths must return a value`...

Comment: Emm..I just realized that it was a piece of **** lolz. Will rewrite it. Thanks guys.